# Validate text field while typing

Tags: javascript, validation

Without any **form** and **submit button**.
if entered character is less than 3.
**show error next to text field**.

Comment: keydown, keyup and keypress events are used for this

Comment: try to code by yourself first, if have any obstacle then ask. we're here to help. we are not free code service provider

Answer (score 1):

You can use a div to show error like so:

```js
    var textbox = document.getElementById("textbox-id");
        divAfterTextBox = document.getElementById("divAfterTextBox-id");
    
    textbox.onkeyup = function(){
        if (textbox.value.length < 3) divAfterTextBox.textContent = "ERROR";
        else divAfterTextBox.textContent = "";
        // divAfterTextBox.textContent = textbox.value.length < 3 ?
        //    "ERROR" : divAfterTextBox.textContent = "";
    }
```

```html
<input id="textbox-id" type="text">
<div id="divAfterTextBox-id"></div>
```